# How to get principal info in JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, taglib

I'm doing a project and need to get user details in JSP. After doing some research, I knew `${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}` can be used to get principal's name. But what if I need another info, example ID (received from Google when login via Google Auth) or password etc. Is there a simple way to do that? I'm using Spring Security taglib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a very simple way of doing this when using `spring security taglib` as you are doing. Just using the authentication tag this way:

`<sec:authentication property="name" />`

Using this way would return the name property of the `Authorization` object, what usually is the same as the principal name. But you can access any other property, even properties in nested objects:

`<sec:authentication property="authorities" />` would return the list of the granted authorities of the Authentication object

`<sec:authentication property="details.sessionId" />` this is a property I sometimes use in a nested object inside the `details` field of the `Authentication` object.